# Brave Tracing currentSpan is null

Tags: java, spring, trace

I am injecting `Tracing` object through constructor in a `service` and trying to get `tracing.tracer().currentSpan()` which is coming as null. `tracing.tracer()` object is initiazed with  `spanHandler`.

I am running it through the test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

If I run the individual test case from eclipse `currentSpan` is initialized properly but when i build the application through `mvn clean install` currentSpan is coming as `null`. Here is the code, I am not sure how the `currentSpan` is initiazed and cant find much about it on internet.

```
@Service
public class Test {

   Tracing tracing;
   
   Test(Tracing tracing) {
       this.tracing = tracing;
   }

   //tracing.tracer().currentSpan() is null
}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class TestJUnit {

}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you don't need `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` if you use  `@SpringBootTest`. Also, can you share the code for the Tracing class as well?

Comment: Tracing class is from `brave-5.12.7.jar` file